# I cannot separate two annotate labels with a comma

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, annotate

First of all, I'm beginner R user. I wanna add R-square and p-value in my chart. But, in a line just separate by a comma. Attached is the code I'm trying to use.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x,y))+
geom_point(shape=1,size=4)+
stat_smooth(method="lm",size=0.6,se=FALSE,colour="black")+
annotate("text",x=30,y=0.45,label=c("italic(r^{2}==0.151)","p==0.226"),parse=TRUE)+
theme_bw(base_size = 12)
```

However, I receive this error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1):
>   label

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to parse multiple expressions as a single expression, you can use `paste` to take the expressions and put them on a single line.  As explained in the other answer, right now you are giving `annotate` two distinct expressions but only one set of x, y coordinates and this is causing the error.

Without a comma, the single expression could look like

`paste("italic(r^{2}) ==", 0.151, "~p==.226")`

This is what you would put as your label in `annotate`.  The additional tilde makes a space between the first and second expressions.

To include the comma, you need `list` in plotmath.  In plotmath, `list` means a comma separated lists (see `?plotmath` for all the available features).  Essentially this means wrapping your entire expression in `list` inside `paste`.

```
paste("list(italic(r^{2}) ==", 0.151, ", p==.226)")
```

And so your annotate code would be

```
+ annotate("text", x=30, y=0.45, label=paste("list(italic(r^{2}) ==", 0.151, ", p==.226)"), parse=TRUE)
```

Comment: Nice. Why couldn't I get that to work. ggplot kept silently failing when I added the comma.

Comment: Ah, because of the list instead of a character array? Why does that make a difference? Odd.

Comment: @MikeWise Yeah, `list` in plotmath is what allows comma separated lists.  Without that you either get an error or don't get a comma.

Comment: Well that is probably the more useful answer. I think you should get the check. Although I explain the error message which is probably useful too, so I will let it sit.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it doesn't get you a comma, because a comma confuses the formula parser.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
data <- data.frame(x=(40+10*rnorm(n)),y=-0.2+0.5*rnorm(n))
ggplot(data)+
  geom_point( aes(x,y),shape=1,size=4)+
  stat_smooth(method="lm",size=0.6,se=FALSE,colour="black")+
  annotate("text",x=c(30,37),y=c(0.45,0.43),label=c("italic(r^{2}==0.151)","p==0.226"),
                                                                           parse=TRUE) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12)
```

Here is the graph.

[image]

Note your error is coming about because you are giving it a vector of length 2 in your `annotate` command, but the `x` and `y` parameter only have length of 1. I adjusted them, but it would be better as one line I think.

To get the comma you can break it up into two `annotate` layers like thi:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
data <- data.frame(x=(40+10*rnorm(n)),y=-0.2+0.5*rnorm(n))
ggplot(data)+
  geom_point( aes(x,y),shape=1,size=4)+
  stat_smooth(method="lm",size=0.6,se=FALSE,colour="black")+
  annotate("text",x=30,y=0.45,label="italic(r^{2}==0.151)", parse=T) +
  annotate("text",x=36,y=0.43,label=", p==0.226",parse=F) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12)
```

Yielding this:

[image]

But I personally think it is too much bother. Go without the comma. Although there might be a way to get it in the formula with an escape sequence or something.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution by aosmith, simply try the following one:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
data <- data.frame(x=(40+10*rnorm(n)),y=-0.2+0.5*rnorm(n))
ggplot(data, aes(x,y))+
  geom_point(shape=1,size=4)+
  stat_smooth(method="lm",size=0.6,se=FALSE,colour="black") +
  annotate(geom = "text",
           x = 30, y = 0.45,
           parse = TRUE,
           label = "italic(r)^{2}==0.151*','~italic(p)==0.226")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJvNB.png)